# Intel Atom Cpu D510 1.66GHz Dual Core 32 bits can run in 16.04 or 17.04?

Tags: 16.04, 17.04, system-requirements

What is the ideal version for this machine (Intel Atom Cpu D510 1.66GHz Dual Core 32 bits) I think the problem is that the minimum requirement is a 2GHz dual processor. What can be another option?

Answer (score 2):

Both options work and I am sure there will be no major performance differences between 17.04 and 16.04, and the documentation says the same. Although if I were you I would install Lubuntu which is a really lightweight version of Ubuntu with less preinstalled packages. Also you did not mention the amount of memory you had so if it is below 1 gig i would recommend Lubuntu.

It is great for low spec systems like the one above, but Ubuntu regular should work as well.

Here is some documentation to read up on for further questions:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

All the best

Comment: The memory is 2GB, so there is not a problem having 1.66GHz instead of 2GHz?

Comment: @Tibie23 you can run all Ubuntu versions with just a 700 MHz processor, I am sorry the link i put was broke i replaced it. I do strongly recommend Xubuntu and Lubuntu thought, for a better experience

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I am gonna try Xubuntu and Lubuntu too

Answer (score -1):

You can find the system requirements at here:
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

[as bellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4apvI.png)

Comment: Where can OP find the system requirements?

Comment: On the homepage,download option , as you proceed to download a package on the ubuntu page, there is always a section Recommended system requirements, which you can see before you really want to. download or simple typing system requirements ubuntu version in the Google search text box and get expected result, nd choose the right version for you

Comment: A direct link to that would be nice. “search for it on Google” is not usually acceptable in answers on Ask Ubuntu (and Stack Exchange in general). Also, could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Again, could you please **[edit]** your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.